# Powerpoint VBA to move and resize multiple objects across a range of slides

Tags: vba, object, powerpoint

I have a really large PowerPoint file and I want to make adjustments to the dimensions of several objects, the font size of each and the position of each object on the slide and I want this to be applied to a range of slides. I am using PowerPoint with Office 365.

I have tried this and it works for only this slide and this object. I want a range of slides (167 -207) and Rectangle 1, 8, and 10.

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(166).Shapes("Rectangle1")
  .Top = 72
  .Left = 72
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code...

```
Dim slideIndex As Long
Dim currentSlide As Slide

For slideIndex = 167 To 207
    Set currentSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(slideIndex)
    With currentSlide
        With .Shapes("Rectange1")
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
            .Left = 72
            .Top = 72
            .Width = 100
            .Height = 100
        End With
        With .Shapes("Rectange8")
            'etc
            '
            '
        End With
        With .Shapes("Rectange10")
            'etc
            '
            '
        End With
    End With
Next slideIndex
```

Change and/or add the settings as desired.

Comment: Thank you for this. It only worked on slide 167.

What if I want each object to be a different position?

Also, I want to change the font size and object size. How can I do this?

Comment: Edit your original post and paste in the current code you're using. I suspect something's mistyped. @domenic's code should deal with every slide in the range you want and set both the size and position of the three rectangles. Note that instead of .Shapes("Rectange1"), it should be .Shapes("Rectangle 1")  ... spelling of "Rectangle" and a space between the word and the number.